# Save image on php imagepng

Tags: php, attachment, content-type

I have in a single PHP file an Upload and then, I use `imagecreatefrompng` to link 2 images, the uploaded image, and another I have in my website.

It works fine in another php file, but when I try to use it in the upload php file, it doesn't save the `imagepng($src, "name.png");`

The code is:

```
imagecopymerge($src, $dest, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 600, 45);
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
$cad = ""; 
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++) { 
    $cad .= substr($str,rand(0,62),1); 
} 
imagepng($src, "fp/$cad.png");
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="flagperfil.png"');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

I can't put `header('Content...` because is a PHP file who has a lot of information. If i put this, then it won't be displayed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you tried changing the code any to debug and see what happens?

Comment: You need to use `readfile()` or `echo` file content to send it to browser;